# /bin/sh: extract command line arguments

Tags: shell, command-line, sh, zsh

I am using `dash` as `/bin/sh`.

My script takes arbitrary number of arguments, and I need to process them such that, one variable contains only the last argument, and another variable contains everything except the last argument.

I know how to do this in `zsh`, but this is unfortunately not compatible with `dash`:

```
last="${@[-1]}"
rest=( ${@[1,-2]} )
```

how can I achieve this in `/bin/sh` ?

Comment: dash doesn't support arrays.

Comment: @400theCat : Neither dash nor sh have arrays. Technically speaking, they do have one single (unnamed) array, which you can set with the `set` command, but you don't have array slices of this solitaire "array" and it is a pain to work with. My suggestion would be that, if you can't stick with `zsh`, you rewrite the whole script from scratch, without paying much attention to the implementation of the original.  Another alternative to consider is to switch to a language with more flexibility, for instance Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rotate the existing arguments until the last argument is first, at which point you can remove it, leaving the remaining `n-1` arguments in their original positions.

```
n=$#  # Number of arguments

# Rotate the aruguments until the last element is the first
while [ "$n" -gt 1 ]; do
  curr=$1
  shift
  set -- "$@" "$curr"
  n=$((n-1))
done

lastarg=$1
shift

# Now $@ is the same as it started, minus its final element.
```

The above code works fine for 1 or more arguments. If there are no arguments, you can check for that before processing, or simply wait for the final `shift` to fail. (In the latter case, `lastarg` will be set to the empty string, which can also happen if the real last argument really is the empty string.)

Answer (score 1):

Posix standard (what dash implements) doesnt even have arrays.

Your only real way would be to use the `shift` builtin and normal arg access:
When $2 is set, $1 is not the last argument. When $2 is not set, we know that $1 is the last arg. Now do this in a loop and handle the arguments accordingly

Comment: Posix sh is about the only shell language that *doesn't* have arrays. They're not just a bash thing.

Comment: I heard a rumor that arrays were being considered for addition to the POSIX specification. While I don't have too much trouble believing that, I've never seen any indication of the exact details, when it might be released, or how long it would take for non-compliant shells to become compliant.

Answer (score 1):

With something like this loop (assumes there's at least one positional parameter):

```sh
rest=""
while [ $# != 1 ]; do
    rest="$rest $1"
    shift
done
last=$1
```

Comment: Will have issues with arguments with spaces, of course. Arrays make dealing with that sort of thing so much easier...

Comment: This is way better than my idea. OP if you are trying to decide use this one instead of mine